# Application Controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am trying to set the id to `default_working_production_id` to `0` if the record has been deleted from the database.  These lines work in the productions controller however don't work in the application controller.  Any thoughts?

```
unless Production.exists?(:id => current_user.default_working_production_id)
    current_user.default_working_production_id = 0
    current_user.default_working_production_name = "No Current Production Set"
end
```

EDIT
Here is my application controller:

```
def index
   @production = Production.where(user_id: current_user)
   @default_working_production = current_user.default_working_production
   unless Production.exists?(:id => current_user.default_working_production_id)
      current_user.default_working_production_id = 0
      current_user.default_working_production_name = "No Current Production Set"
   end 
end
```

in my productions_controller, I have the following create function

```
def create
    @production = Production.new(production_params)
    @production.user = current_user
    @production.user_name = current_user.name

    if @production.save
        current_user.default_working_production_id = @production.id
        current_user.default_working_production_name = @production.title
        respond_to do |format|
            if current_user.save
                format.html { redirect_to productions_path } 
            else
                format.html { redirect_to productions_path, notice: "Error.  Please contact support." }
            end
        end
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: show the whole method, as well as how you are trying to use it

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: so, when do you want the index action in the Application controller to kick in?

Comment: you have an `end` missing at the end of the `unless` in the `index` action of the application controller. Is it missing in you actual code, or just in the SO question?

Comment: Also how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: the end was a SO copy/paste error

Answer (score 2):

This should not be put in the controller - it will add extra processing for every single call, leading your app to run markedly slower.

It looks like you'd be best using `defaults` in your database:

```
$ rails g migration AddDefaultsToUsers

#db/migrate/add_defaults_to_users________.rb
class AddDefaultsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      change_column :users, :default_working_production_id, :integer, default: 0
      change_column :users, :default_working_production_name, :string, default: "No Current Production Set" 
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

This will allow you to set the `default_working_production_id` and `default_working_production_name` as whatever is required, and if they're not in existence, the *database* will populate them with `0` and `No Current Production Set` respectively.

As a rule of thumb, if you can get away with the database performing calculations (rather than your web server), you *must* do it. So many people forget that the db server is there to manipulate your data for you -- there's no point letting your application do it when you have the entire power of another server to perform tasks such as setting a default etc.

---

If you wanted to keep this in your Rails app, you'd want to use the [`after_destroy`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveRecord%2FCallbacks%3Aafter_destroy):

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_destroy :set_user

   private

   def set_user
      self.user.update(default_working_production_id: 0, default_working_production_name: "No Current Production Set") if self.user
   end
end
```

Comment: I currently have `default_working_production_id` and `default_working_production_name` in the users db, however I dont have the default attributes.  Would this still work and be able to see when a production (from the productions db) is deleted?

Comment: If you had `dependent: :destroy` on the association, I think it would remove the data which would warrant the default being invoked

Comment: the dependent destroy seems to delete the user that's signed in... I'm confused as to why I cant have a statement along the lines of `unless Production.where(:id current_user.default_working_production_id) current_user.default_working_production_id = 0 end`